# GPO's between domains with a trust relationship

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Is it possible to apply a GPO from one domain to another domain with a trust relationship?  We have a GPO that adds a management security group to the local admin group of domain joined computers.  My understanding is that the GPO of Domain can only be applied to objects within its own domain. Could a security group of Domain A be added to a GPO created within Domain B to be added to the local admin group of computers within Domain B?

GPO - Domain A  <- Trust -> Domain B

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that the GPO of Domain can only be applied to objects within its own domain.

Your understanding is spot-on - there is no such thing as a cross-domain GPO

> Could a security group of Domain A be added to a GPO created within Domain B to be added to the local admin group of computers within Domain B?

### Yes!

Most certainly. If you use the Local Users and Groups group policy preference settings, you specify a Local Group name (ie. Administrators), and then add an explicit list of members. These members can come from anywhere within your own forest, but you can also choose security principals from other domains that you trust!

Just change the "Location" in the object picker:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the whole story there

Comment: I tried that, but when I change locations, I only see my domain listed and not the other domain with whom we have the trust.

Comment: The "GPO domain", in this case DomainB, needs to trust DomainA, not the other way around